# is there any way to show MySQL table lock history

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.7.26,is there any way to show table lock history?I know how to check current table lock using:

```
show OPEN TABLES where In_use > 0;
```

I want to avoid table lock in my SQL query,so view the history may help.Current lock may not get all locked table(Maybe the locked table query not execute right now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today I found a way to show this in MySQL 5.7:

```
show engine innodb status
```

this is the part of result output:

```
====================================
2020-09-25 10:36:53 0x7ff4b4c5d700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 12 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 762213 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 139997 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 902210
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 363879865
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 448819672
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 425739262, OS waits 209673117
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 4271714439, OS waits 133598673
RW-sx spins 135926, rounds 2757000, OS waits 52788
Spin rounds per wait: 425739262.00 RW-shared, 4271714439.00 RW-excl, 20.28 RW-sx
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2020-09-25 10:10:41 0x7ff4b4ce1700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 841893940, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 108348, OS thread handle 140688980530944, query id 184994716 172.19.104.233 root Searching rows for update
UPDATE r_room_seat SET status = 1,
        id = (SELECT @update_id := id),
        user_id = 62659,
        robot_flag = 1
        WHERE room_play_id = 539 and status = 0 and online = 1
        LIMIT 1
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 3493 page no 528 n bits 176 index PRIMARY of table `room_db`.`r_room_seat` trx id 841893940 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 56 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 20; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 000000000000d649; asc        I;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000322d9b9a; asc   2-  ;;
 2: len 7; hex 3e000040042eda; asc >  @ . ;;
 3: len 8; hex 800000000000021b; asc         ;;
 4: len 8; hex 8000000000000097; asc         ;;
 5: len 8; hex 800000000000f4d5; asc         ;;
 6: len 8; hex 7fffffffffffffff; asc         ;;
 7: len 8; hex 8000017452aa2c5e; asc    tR ,^;;
 8: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 9: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 10: len 8; hex 8000017452aa2c5e; asc    tR ,^;;
 11: len 8; hex 8000017452aa2c5e; asc    tR ,^;;
 12: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 13: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 14: len 8; hex 8000000000000005; asc         ;;
 15: len 10; hex 48415050595f5241494e; asc HAPPY_RAIN;;
 16: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 17: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
 18: len 8; hex 8000000000000074; asc        t;;
 19: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 841893905, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
746 lock struct(s), heap size 90320, 128960 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 100540, OS thread handle 140688982152960, query id 184994612 172.19.104.233 root Sending data
UPDATE r_room_seat s
        SET s.status = 1,
        s.room_play_id = (SELECT @update_id := max(room_play_id)),
        s.user_id = (
            case when s.seat_num = 1
            then 63182
            when s.seat_num = 2
            then 16472
            else -1 end
        ),
        s.robot_flag = (
            case when s.seat_num = 1
            then 1
            when s.seat_num = 2
            then 0
            else 0 end
        )
        WHERE s.status = 0
        and s.online = 1
        and s.room_play_id in (
            select room_play_id
            from (
                select room_play_id as room_play_id
                from r_room_seat
                where room_id = 166
                and status = 0
                group by room_play_id
                having count(*) = 2
                limit 1
            ) a
        )
        and s.room_id = 166
        LIMIT 2
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 3493 page no 528 n bits 176 index PRIMARY of table `room_db`.`r_room_seat` trx id 841893905 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
```

you can get the dead lock information and analysis.